# Copy and pasting multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, cells

I am trying to copy and paste several cells from one workbook into another.  I am trying to get the source cells into one row and loop with other workbooks to copy and paste cells below the previous (hence lastrow statement).

The code I have does not seem to be working and is severely inefficient!  As you will notice the cells are not in a neat range that can be easily copied.

```
See below:
    ...        
        lastrow2 = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        shtWBc2.Unprotect Password:="QC"

        shtWBc2.Range("C4").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C5").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("C" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("D" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("E" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("F" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("G" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("H" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S10").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("I" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C14").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("J" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C15").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("K" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("L" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("M" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("N" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("O" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("P" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S20").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("Q" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C24").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("R" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C25").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("S" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("T" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("U" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("V" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("W" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("X" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S30").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("Y" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C34").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("Z" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C35").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AA" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AB" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AC" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AD" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AE" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AF" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S40").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AG" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C54").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AH" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C55").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AI" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AJ" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AK" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AL" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AM" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AN" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S60").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AO" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("V56").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AP" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("V57").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AQ" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("W65").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AR" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C44").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AS" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("C45").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AT" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("D50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AU" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AV" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("J50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AW" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("M50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AX" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AY" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("S50").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("AZ" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("V46").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("BA" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("V47").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("BB" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("P65").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("BC" & lastrow2).Value
        shtWBc2.Range("G65").Value = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("BD" & lastrow2).Value


        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        WBc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    End If
Next F........
```

At present, nothing is getting copied over and it takes a long while to get through four loops - I will be doing up to 40 loops.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 lastrow2 = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

This is giving you the row number for the first row with **no** content in ColB, not the last row with any content in ColB.  Maybe you need to drop the `+ 1`  ?

Edited to reverse direction of copy:

```
a) copying *from* shtBatchwbkBGAsumm 
b) copying *to* shtBatchwbkBGAsumm
```

Here's one alternative approach:

```
Dim arr, i As Long, rw As Range

'create an array of your "destination" ranges
arr = Array("C4", "C5", "G10", "J10", "M10", "P10") 'add the rest here...

'(a) assign the last row with data to the variable "rw"
'Set rw = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).EntireRow

'(b) assign the first empty row to the variable "rw"
Set rw = shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Offset(1,0)

shtWBc2.Unprotect Password:="QC"

'lbound here will be zero, ubound=(# of ranges-1)
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    'shtWBc2.Range(arr(i)).Value = rw.Cells(i + 2).Value 'direction (a)
    rw.Cells(i + 2).Value = shtWBc2.Range(arr(i)).Value 'direction (b)

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
WBc.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Here's I'm using `rw` to represent a range (row) on `shtBatchwbkBGAsumm` - makes for cleaner syntax.

E.g. compare:

```
rw.cells(,"B").Value
```

vs.

```
shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.Range("B" & lastrow2).Value
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. You code does seem moore logical and compact.  It also processes quicker than my way.  However, the array is not visible where it is supposed to be.  My reasoning for the 'lastrow' arguement was as you pointed out... to find the first available empty row and paste the data there.  The data is being copied into a template with column A, Row 1 & row 2 occupied with headers.  Hence the first available empty row will be B3:BD3... after the first loop the next available row is B4:BD4...B5:BD5....etc. At present the problem is that nothing is getting copied over....

Comment: Well, I am having no success in this... The values are just not appearing where they are supposed to (or at all).  I have tried to rearrange a couple of arguements which have worked for me in the past, but nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can edit your question to add your new code - and maybe also explain exactly which sheets you're copying between and where they're located. In your comment above you seem to suggest you're copying *to* `shtBatchwbkBGAsumm` but the code in your question suggests copying in the opposite direction...

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim.  I did post earlier to elaborate on my code, but it was not accepted by the moderators.  I am indeed pasting the array from shtWBc2 to a single row in shtBatchBGAsumm, preferably in the order the array is stated - and I apologize for the misdirection...I thought that my code could work both ways and it was a matter of which sheet was active that determined the direction.

Comment: I think you tried to update my answer - it was rejected before I saw it. Better to update your own question. If you need the copy to work in two directions then that's going to be more complex.

Comment: I see. No, not both ways...I agree, too complex. Just from shtWBc2 to shtBatchwbkBGAsumm.  I will edit the code now.  Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't edit my answer - that's typically not done here, and it will just get rejected. Edit *your question*.

Comment: The change I made was to declare shtWBc2 before 'shtWBc2.Unprotect Password:="QC"'- the intention was that shtWB2 would be activated and follow through with the process.  Which change would have to be made to you existing code to copy the datta in the way I need - i.e. from shtWBc2 to shtBatchBGAsumm?  Also, can you explain the 'rw' arguement you declared.  what is your intention?  To add, shtBatchBGAsumm is a batch summary that extracts data from several workbooks (shtWBc2 is a template which data is copied into), hence the looping function.  Thus i need each array copied below the previous.

Comment: Many thanks Tim!!!  It has worked beautifully!  And thanks for your patience.... being a beginner I am having to build my repository of coding knowledge through this website (alongside other demands).  Your use of simple syntax has helped me a great deal! Moderators, please equip Tim with another gold badge :) !